# How to add a reaction to a message on user behalf using Discord API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a role assigning bot using reactions on a special message. The tricky part is keeping the reactions consistent. I want to pre-populate the roles with users who already have them when I create the message. I also want to prevent users from removing their reaction for one role without choosing another. I've seen a bot like this: when I attempted to remove my reaction to my role the bot re-added it for me. However I couldn't find any API which would allow adding a reaction on someone's behalf. Nor could I find any way to prevent a user from removing their reaction on a message. How did it do that? Do I miss something? Or is it an undocumented API feature?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, **you can't force add reactions as a user**. If you still know what's the name of the bot that did that let me know and I'll try figure it out.

The only thing you can do is **remove a reaction** from a user.

You can't also prevent the user from adding/removing reactions. You can only prevent them from adding a reaction with a new emoji (users with `Send Messages` permission can add new emojis to the reaction. So if a message has only 2 emojis as reactions, he can add a 3rd, but if he doesn't have that permission he can only add reactions with the emojis already present)

Comment: The bot which seemingly did this was yagpdb.xyz. Also I kind of can prevent the users from adding unrelated reactions: my bot detects addition and removes any reactions not in the list. This way most of the users have the rigit to add reactions but not on this particular message.

Comment: YAGPDB.xyz can reset reactions on a rolemenu.  https://docs.yagpdb.xyz/commands/all-commands#rolemenu-resetreactions  But the Discord API does not appear to support creating a reaction on behalf of a user.id.  https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-reaction